# How to add item to array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I have a loop that is generating about 150 unique strings.  How can I add these strings to an array?

Here is my loop:

```
for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < projectCount; intCounter ++)
{
    var projectname = project.value[intCounter].name;
    var releaseUri = "http://tfs1:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/" + projectname + "/_apis/release/releases?api-version=3.0-preview.2&searchText=911&minCreatedTime=" + date + "T00:00:00.00Z";
    Console.WriteLine(releaseUri);
}
```

The `Console.WriteLine(releaseUri)` prints each url.  but I would like to store the releaseUri in an array.

Comment: `myArray[intCounter] = releaseUri;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ShaneP,

You will need to declare an array outside of the for loop like so.

```
string[] releaseUriArray = new string[projectCount];

for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < projectCount; intCounter ++)
{
    var projectname = project.value[intCounter].name;
    var releaseUri = "http://tfs1:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/" + projectname + "/_apis/release/releases?api-version=3.0-preview.2&searchText=911&minCreatedTime=" + date + "T00:00:00.00Z";
    // Here you are adding the releaseUri strings to the releaseUriArray
    releaseUriArray[intCounter] = releaseUri;

} 

// print your uris from the array here
for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < projectCount; intCounter ++)
{
    var releaseUri = releaseUriArray[intCounter];
    Console.WriteLine(releaseUri);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Lists are normally better than arrays.

```
    var releaseUris = new List<string>();
    foreach(var project in projects)
    {
        var releaseUri = $"http://tfs1:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/" + project.projectname + "/_apis/release/releases?api-version=3.0-preview.2&searchText=911&minCreatedTime=" + project.date + "T00:00:00.00Z";
        releaseUris.Add(releaseUri);
    }
```

Comment: Huh, rly? Initialization new instance of `List` without parameters creates an object to store 4 elements. When you add the fifth element `List` will allocate new array to store 8 elements and then when you add the 9-th it will alloacte another to store 16 and so on. It's not normally better if you know array length and not gonna to change array after initialization

Comment: Just as a side note, you can pass in the size to the List constructor:  `new List<string>(projectCount)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array in this case as you know the number of elements. Initialize it and set the items as you go

```
var arr = new string[projectCount];
for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < projectCount; intCounter ++)
{
    var projectname = project.value[intCounter].name;
    var releaseUri = "http://tfs1:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/" + projectname + "/_apis/release/releases?api-version=3.0-preview.2&searchText=911&minCreatedTime=" + date + "T00:00:00.00Z";
    Console.WriteLine(releaseUri);
    arr[intCounter] = releaseUri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you now `projectCount` then you can create an array with needed element numbers and just set its items by index.

```
var urls = new string[projectCount];
for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < projectCount; intCounter ++)
{
    var projectname = project.value[intCounter].name;
    var releaseUri = "http://tfs1:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/" + projectname + "/_apis/release/releases?api-version=3.0-preview.2&searchText=911&minCreatedTime=" + date + "T00:00:00.00Z";
    urls[i] = releaseUri;
}
```

Or you can just use an [dynamic array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) and add elements using [`Add()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add) method to be able to change array size after initialization.

```
var urls = new List<string>();
for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < projectCount; intCounter ++)
{
    var projectname = project.value[intCounter].name;
    var releaseUri = "http://tfs1:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/" + projectname + "/_apis/release/releases?api-version=3.0-preview.2&searchText=911&minCreatedTime=" + date + "T00:00:00.00Z";
    urls.Add(releaseUri);
}
```

Also you no need to use loops and can solve your problem with just 1 string of code using [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/):

```
var urls = project
              .value
              .Select(p => "http://tfs1:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/" + p.projectname + "/_apis/release/releases?api-version=3.0-preview.2&searchText=911&minCreatedTime=" + date + "T00:00:00.00Z")
              .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this would be to create a template Uri that has placeholders for project name and date (using `{0}` and `{1}` in the string), then with some `Linq` extension methods (`Select` and `ToList`) and `string.Format`, you can and generate your strings from an `Enumerable.Range`:

```
// Project name and date will be inserted where {0} and {1} are below
string uriTemplate = "http://tfs1:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/{0}/_apis/release/" +
    "releases?api-version=3.0-preview.2&searchText=911&minCreatedTime={1}T00:00:00.00Z";

string[] releaseUris = Enumerable.Range(0, projectCount)
    .Select(i => string.Format(uriTemplate, project.value[i], date))
    .ToArray();
```